# Comparison Property for Second Order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $0< a(t)\leq b(t)\leq c(t)$ for all $t$.  Is it the case that the solution to $x''+b(t)x=0,x(t_0)=x_0,x'(t_1)=x_1$ is bounded between the solutions to $x''+a(t)x=0, x(t_0)=x_0,x'(t_1)=x_1$ and $x''+c(t)x=0,x(t_0)=x_0,x'(t_1)=x_1$?  It seems like it should be true, and I understand this in the first order case, but I have a hard time thinking about it in the second order case.

Comment: The equations are second order and you give only an initial condition; you cannot talk about "the solution".

Comment: good point.  I made a stupid mistake.  I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

Take $a=1,b=4,c=9$

the solutions are

$$x_a(t)=A_1\cos(t)+A_2\sin(t),$$

$$x_b(t)=B_1\cos(2t)+B_2\sin(2t),$$

and

$$x_c(t)=C_1\cos(3t)+C_2\sin(3t)$$

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are not constants. You can check that your solution is incorrect for example with the equation $x''+t\,x=0$.

Comment: I do not like down voting in cases like this.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Comment: Can we at least say that if the solutions, $x_a(t),x_c(t)$ are bounded, then so is $x_b(t)$?